# Dynamic Query Criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to make a Microsoft Access query depend on a value in another form's textbox.

This is the criteria, as it is now. Basically, any date between April 1st 2014, and March 31st 2015. This works well.

```
>=#2014-04-01# And <#2015-04-01#
```

I'd like to have a textbox with the year (with the current example 2014), and make the query criteria (2014, 2014+1) depend on this value.

I've tried to split the above syntax, then concatenate in the criteria, as such:

```
">=#" & "2014" & "-04-01# And <#" & "2015" & "-04-01#"
```

And I get an error "Data types in the criterion expression are incompatible".

**1. Is it possible to concatenate in the query criteria?**
I have also tried the SQL CONCAT(string1,string2,string3,..), to no avail.
If this is possible, then I guess I can use [Forms]![Form1].[Textbox1] and ([Forms]![Form1].[Textbox1] + 1) to replace the years.
If this is not possible...

**2. Is there a better way to make the query criteria dynamic?**

I tried to make [the following solution](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/211550-query-vba) work by creating a module with similar code:

```
Private m_varQueryParam As Variant
Public Function SetQueryParam(ByVal sValue as Variant)
m_varQueryParam = sValue
End Function
Public Function GetQueryParam() As Variant
GetQueryParam = m_varQueryParam
End Function

Query:
SELECT * FROM tblYourTable WHERE [FilterField] = GetQueryParam()

The VBA Code to launch the query will look like this.
SetQueryParam "your value here"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryYourQueryHere"
```

But I simply do not understand how to get this to work.

EDIT: I created a simple access database, to try to get this to work.

- Textbox1, default value =Date()
- bSave, button
- tDateInfo, table: date (date/time), info (text) with random dates and info.
- Query1:

`SELECT tDateInfo.date, tDateInfo.info
FROM tDateInfo
WHERE (((tDateInfo.date)=GetQueryParam()));`

Here's the form's vba code

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub bSave_Click()
sValue = Me.TextBox1.Value
SetQueryParam (sValue)
End Sub
```

Here's the modules vba code

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
'is this necessary?

Private m_varQueryParam As Variant
Public Function SetQueryParam(ByVal sValue As Variant)
m_varQueryParam = sValue
End Function
Public Function GetQueryParam() As Variant
GetQueryParam = m_varQueryParam
End Function
```

And the query criteria is `GetQueryParam()`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

The following code defines the SQL as I require it, and changes the SQL for the Access query.

It's not ideal, because it requires me to rewrite all the SQL for the queries, but it works.

```
Sub ChangeQuery()
Dim Year, sqlTwo, StartDate, EndDate As String
Year = Me.txtYear.Value
StartDate = "4/1/" & Year
EndDate = "4/1/" & (Year + 1)
sqlTwo = "SELECT DateCalc.ID, DateCalc.FilterField FROM DateCalc WHERE (((DateCalc.FilterField)>=#" & StartDate & "# And DateCalc.FilterField<#" & EndDate & "#));"
tbTest.Value = sqlTwo
Dim oDB As Database
Dim oQuery As QueryDef
Set oDB = CurrentDb
Set oQuery = oDB.QueryDefs("Query1")
oQuery.SQL = sqlTwo
Set oQuery = Nothing
Set oDB = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click()
ChangeQuery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling parameters and form fields is a little tricky with VBA. I created a simple table similar to yours as follows:
    CREATE TABLE DateCalc (
      ID AutoNumber,
      FilterField DateTime
    )

The following code will return your desired results:

```
Sub testthis()
    Dim db As dao.database
    Set db = CurrentDb ' use current database
    Dim qd As dao.QueryDef
    Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("") ' create anaonymous querydef
    ' the SQL statement correctly concatenates the parameter (Useyear) and mm/dd strings
    qd.sql = "SELECT * FROM DateCalc WHERE [FilterField] >= [UseYear]" & "-04-01 And [FilterField] < [UseYear]+1" & "-04-01"
    qd!UseYear = Forms!DateCalc!txtYear ' set the value of se year from the Form WHICH MUST BE OPEN
                                        ' AND the TetBox filled with the year you desire - 2014 for this example.
    Dim rs As dao.recordSet
    Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
    MsgBox "ID=" & rs(0) & ", Date=" & rs(1)
End Sub
```

**NEW VERSION**
Sorry, there were a couple of date formatting problems with  the first solution that the following code resolves. There are a number of other reasons for the error, so be sure the FormName is "DateCalc" and the TextBox is named "txtYear".

You should be able to generalize the following code for all your queries (do those actually work?). I pass the TableName in now as an example:

```
Sub DateFilter(TableName As String)
    Dim db As dao.database
    Set db = CurrentDb ' use current database
    Dim qd As dao.QueryDef
    Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("") ' create anaonymous querydef
    ' the SQL statement correctly concatenates the parameter (Useyear) and mm/dd strings
    Dim UseYear As Integer
    UseYear = Forms!DateCalc!txtYear
    Dim BegDate As Date
    BegDate = CDate(UseYear & "-04-01")
    Dim EndDate As Date
    EndDate = CDate((UseYear + 1) & "-04-01")
    qd.sql = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE [FilterField] >= [UseBegDate] And [FilterField] < [UseEndDate]"
    qd!UseBegDate = BegDate
    qd!UseEndDate = EndDate

    Dim rs As dao.recordSet
    Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
    Do While Not rs.EOF
      MsgBox "ID=" & rs(0) & ", Date=" & rs(1)
      rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: ron, thanks for your input. using this code, I get an error 3021 No current record. What is the solution? :/ Also, is there another solution? as I currently have 20 queries that already exist, and they need to have the same criteria for the date...

Comment: Ron, thanks again. I tried DateFilter(DateCalc) and Access threw error 3131, Syntax error in FROM clause. If the concatenation works, I can't find the syntax error. And yes, the queries work with ">=#2014-04-01# And <#2015-04-01#", but next year, I'd like to not have to rewrite the queries, or create new ones...